# Need help to recover broken Nextcloud snap installation

Tags: nextcloud, snap

I somehow managed to break my Nextcloud server! I guess I run a wrong snapd.service command and it broke my Nextcloud. The command that allegedly broke it was this:

sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service

Then I managed to get the server back running, but after some period I noticed that, for example, background cron job to scan for files inside the Nextcloud had stopped. Looking into this I found that whole snap service is throwing errors, and I no longer know what to do. Every command involving snap results in errors, which I do not understand.

Some examples cmd:  results in:
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get http://localhost/v2/snaps: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

cmd:  results in:
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snapctl: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Help much appreciated!